# Texts Do Not Change When I Change The Font Size

Tags: photoshop

Does anyone encounter the same issue with the Photoshop?

I have been trying to change my wording sizes, every time I select the text layer, highlight and click the size/fonts (image below), and scroll my mouse to chose, the text on the layer does not change and no preview. Unless I select it and it changes.

It is difficult and wasting time to actually try one by one manually rather than scrolling mouse and see the preview. Do I need to do some setting changes? Help please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press and Hold the left mouse button on the 'tT' icon of the fontsize and drag it left or right to decrease or increase the size of the font with a live preview.

I hope this helped :)

Comment: the text layer should be highlighted.

Comment: When you will hover over the tT icon.. this icon will appear - https://n6-img-fp.akamaized.net/free-icon/double-arrow_318-133577.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg   a double sided arrow which means you can increase or decrease the size by dragging it left or right.

Comment: I know, that icon appears, but when i drag it to the left and right, the text on the board doesn't change according to size changes.

Comment: In the latest Photoshop version, previewing font changes doesn't work anymore. I suspect it has to do with the fix to the bug in "text-adjustments done to previously transformed copy".